# Exception design mismatch to the requirement in application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, exception, maven

In my application, i have decided to integrate hoptoad error logging system in it. But as the application is huge, it requires a lot of manual work to call the log method present in the hoptoad class in each and every `catch` block. As of now, i have included the method call for error logging in few catch blocks. This is a spring, hibernate, flex, drools, maven managed application.

```
hoptoadUtil.logToHoptoad(throwable);
```

My doubt is - can i call this method globally for the application ,i.e., ask spring to call this log method in hoptoad class wherever any exception or error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring AOP might help you, check this link for an example

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-aop-examples-advice/